# Equivalent Definition of $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

This is from Folland Real Analysis section 2.6 where he gave a definition of $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure

> Lebesgue measure $m^n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the completion of the
> n-fold product of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with itself, that
> is, the completion of $m \times \cdots \times m$ on
> $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}} \bigotimes \cdots \bigotimes
>  \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}} = \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ **or
> equivalently** the completion of $m \times \cdots \times m$ on
> $\mathcal{L} \bigotimes \cdots \bigotimes \mathcal{L}$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesgue measuarble set on $\mathbb{R}$.

Why "**or equivalently**" holds, why these two product measures' completion is the same one?

EDIT: This is indeed a gap here, which Folland failed to explain. And I found a proof somewhere else. I will post the proof later when I have time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitions are indeed equivalent. Recall that  Given a (possibly incomplete) measure space $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$, there is an extension $(X, \mathcal A_1, \mu_1)$ of this measure space that is complete. The smallest such extension (i.e., the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A_1$) is called the completion of the measure space [1].

Let $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal A_1, \mu_1)$
be the completion of $m \times \cdots \times m$ on
$\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}} \otimes \cdots \otimes
 \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}} = \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$.

Now the product $\sigma$-algebra  $$\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n} :=\mathcal{L}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{L} $$ is sandwiched between
$\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $\mathcal A_1$, because $m$ on  $\mathcal{L}$
is the completion of $m$ on $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$.
Thus $\mathcal A_1$ is a complete $\sigma$-algebra (for $m^n$) which contains $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$. It must be the smallest such $\sigma$-algebra, since it is the smallest complete $\sigma$-algebra that contains
$\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure

Comment: This looks good to me. But I think If you prove $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$ is not a complete measure(There are many obvious examples), then this answer would be perfect.